# Why doesn't this ObjC block release its captured references when it's released? Failing unit test included

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, objective-c-blocks, xctest

I've run into an issue where an object captured within a block doesn't seem to get released, even after all references to the object and block have been set to `nil`.

To illustrate this issue I put together this really simple unit test which *should* pass but doesn't:

```
/* Headers */

@interface BlockTestTests : XCTestCase

@end

// A simple class that calls a callback when it's deallocated
@interface Dummy : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^deallocCallback)();

@end

/* Implementation */

@implementation BlockTestTests

- (void)testExample {
    XCTestExpectation *exp = [self expectationWithDescription:@"strong reference should be deallocated when its capturing block is released"];

    Dummy *dummy = [Dummy new];

    dummy.deallocCallback = ^{
        [exp fulfill];
    };

    void(^capturingBlock)() = ^{
        // Captures a strong reference to the dummy
        id capturedStrongReference = dummy;
    };

    capturingBlock = nil;
    dummy = nil;

    // At this point we would expect that all references to the
    // object have been cleared and it should get deallocated.
    // Just to be safe, we even wait 2 seconds, but it never happens...        

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:2.0 handler:nil];
}

@end

@implementation Dummy

- (void)dealloc {
    _deallocCallback();
}

@end
```

Can you tell me why this test fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `capturingBlock` is creating an autoreleased object (probably via the capture, but possibly the block itself). If you put an `@autoreleasepool` around it, it'll do what you want:

```
  @autoreleasepool {
    void(^capturingBlock)() = ^{
      // Captures a strong reference to the dummy
      id capturedStrongReference = dummy;
    };
    capturingBlock = nil;
    dummy = nil;
  }
```

A more consistent approach is to put an `@autoreleasepool` around your entire test (after the creation of `exp` and before `waitForExpectations...`). That's something you can do for any test that you want to validate that objects are deallocated by the time the pool drains. Like this:

```
- (void)testExample {
  XCTestExpectation *exp = [self expectationWithDescription:@"strong reference should be deallocated when its capturing block is released"];

  @autoreleasepool {
    Dummy *dummy = [Dummy new];

    dummy.deallocCallback = ^{
      [exp fulfill];
    };

    void(^capturingBlock)() = ^{
      // Captures a strong reference to the dummy
      id capturedStrongReference = dummy;
    };
    capturingBlock = nil;
    dummy = nil;
  }

  [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:2.0 handler:nil];
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course! Thank you for the thorough response.